# how to retrieve tree nodes count for all records in mysql?

Tags: mysql, tree

I have this mysql query:

```
`select a.ID, a.parentID, a.name,
count(distinct b.ID) as level1,
count(distinct c.ID) as level2,
count(distinct d.ID) as level3,
count(distinct e.ID) as level4,
count(distinct f.ID) as level5,
count(distinct g.ID) as level6,
count(distinct h.ID) as level7,
count(distinct i.ID) as level8,
count(distinct j.ID) as level9,
count(distinct k.ID) as level10
from members a
left join members b on b.parentID = a.ID
left join members c on c.parentID = b.ID
left join members d on d.parentID = c.ID
left join members e on e.parentID = d.ID
left join members f on f.parentID = e.ID
left join members g on g.parentID = f.ID
left join members h on h.parentID = g.ID
left join members i on i.parentID = h.ID
left join members j on j.parentID = i.ID
left join members k on k.parentID = j.ID
left join members l on l.parentID = k.ID
where a.ID = 1`
```

How do i have to update this query to allow get all id's in members table, not just to retrieve 1 query result at the time.
I would like to replace where a.ID = 1 per something like:

```
`where a.id IN (select ID from members)`
```

The problem is, when I do that, I get just one row with all counts grouped. I want to get the list of levels in a list of ID's.

The result is this:

```
`ID | parent | name        | lv1 | lv2 | lv3 | lb4 | lv5 | lv6 | lv7 | lv8 | lv9 | lv10 |`
`1  | 0      | Manish Shah | 3   | 9   | 27  | 81  | 36  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0    |`
```

And I want

```
`ID | parent | name        | lv1 | lv2 | lv3 | lb4 | lv5 | lv6 | lv7 | lv8 | lv9 | lv10 |`
`1  | 0      | Manish Shah | 3   | 9   | 27  | 81  | 36  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0    |`
`2  | 4      | luiset Shah | 3   | 9   | 27  | 81  | 36  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0    |`
`3  | 8      | sarah kanna | 3   | 9   | 27  | 81  | 36  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0    |`
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your data, that is

```
WHERE a.id IN (2341,2342,2343,2344)
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: There is an extra field named introID which is the ID of the member that introduced to the program another member, so, how do I get the introID total per level?

Comment: @LuisParada What's the difference? I mean, you can do DISTINCT count on any field... If it is a different one, then please ask it in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all members, you can just drop the `WHERE` clause, but you will need a `GROUP BY a.ID`